# WP7 Music+Video hub integration possibilities

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player

Is there currently a way for my WP7 app to:

1. Scan for available audio files, that have been transferred to the phone via Zune?
2. Start a playback of a selected audio file from within my app's UI, but still have an ability to "record to a file" the point, at which the playback was ended (or paused), so I would be able to allow the user to resume at the same point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can use the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) to find the songs/albums that's available on the phone.
2. You'll use the integrated player for playing music, so if the user pauses the play, the user can simply use the standard music interface to resume play. It's not the task of your application.

Comment: If a user plays a different audio, the point, on which he dropped listening to this particular one will be lost. I wand the user to be able to resume at the point where he left off, even after he has listened to a different media.

Comment: Can I play an audio files from within my application, even though I have discovered them using MediaLibrary?

Comment: I think you should spend some time reading up on the media functionality for the phone, before asking any more questions!

Comment: I can see that I can play an audio in my apps' UI from Music + Video hub code sample from Microsoft. At this point we can consider the question answered. Thanks.